# How to uninstall "try ubuntu" and return to old OS

Tags: system-installation, uninstall

When we install ubuntu to pc, it gives choice: to try linux or install linux. If we select try, we have a way to load from Windows f.e. But if we understood ehat we should stay on Windows, how to remove this trial version?

Answer (score 4):

Simply reboot into Windows.

The "Try Ubuntu" environment runs entirely in memory (RAM). NOTHING is installed. Your hard drive (HDD/SSD) is completely untouched.

There is nothing to uninstall unless you specifically installed it.

Answer (score 0):

I on occasion borrow computers (*not my hardware & away from places I regularly attend*) where I don't want to touch/use the owners microsoft windows system, I use their machine with Ubuntu (or *flavor*) on thumb-drive, using the [Try Ubuntu](https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/try-ubuntu-before-you-install) type option.

On shutdown the windows will reboot (*in almost all cases*) without change just as per @user535733's answer.

On rare occasion (*I'm told later sometimes, or receive a phone call of mock-complaint*) their windows reported the clock was changed.  Microsoft windows defaults to using local time by default, where as Ubuntu will use internet time by default.

I've not worked out why this *sometimes* occurs, but is easily corrected using the machine's normal windows clock functions (*usually by the owner*).

Nothing is uninstalled; at worst a clock adjustment maybe necessary.